Unbiased estimator of the reversed regression
Suppose I have random variables $X$ and $Y$. I am interested in an unbiased estimator of $\mathbb{E}[Y | X]$, but I performed regression the other way and have $\mathbb{E}[X |Y]$.  Under what data generating distribution and further assumption, is it known that I can construct an unbiased estimator $\mathbb{E}[Y | X] = \beta \mathbb{E}[X |Y]$? Thanks.

Here's a hint. Refer to the other way $\beta$ with subscript 2 and the $\beta$ you want with subscript 1.  Write down the formula for the estimate: $\hat{\beta_1}$. Write down the formula for, $\hat{\beta_2}$, the estimate of $\beta_2$. Then, figure out what you have to multiply $\hat{\beta_2}$ by so that it's expectation is equal to $\beta_1$. Then, by definition, $\hat{\beta}_2$ multiplied by that correction factor is your unbiased estimator of ${\beta_1}$.
